# How can I print the lines in a file that contain two regex where one is the substring of another

Tags: text-processing

If the file has-

```
apple,orange,banana
orange
ora,orange,apple
apple,ora
orange,apple,ora,banana
```

I want to print only lines containing `ora` and `orange`-

```
ora,orange,apple
orange,apple,ora,banana
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single ***egrep***:

```
egrep 'ora\b.*orange|orange.*ora\b' file
```

The output:

```
ora,orange,apple
orange,apple,ora,banana
```

---

Or with single ***sed*** expression:

```
sed -n '/orange/{/ora\b/p}' file
ora,orange,apple
orange,apple,ora,banana
```

---

In both approaches `\b` (word boundary) is used.

Answer (score 1):

Grep for whole words:

```
$ grep -w orange foo.csv | grep -w ora
ora,orange,apple
orange,apple,ora,banana
```

`-w` means that matching text should be surrounded by non-word characters (word characters are alphabets, digits, underscore).